# azure ad users to combobox without azure sql database wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, entity-framework

I am trying to show all users from the azure AD of the company i work for.
I don't have a lot of experience using Azure. This company doesn't have an account with azure sql database so that is off the table.
Now i am wondering if it is possible to fetch all the users from azure and put them into a combobox in my wpf app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview).

This API contains an [endpoint for listing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) all users.

Comment: I have tried to use the following code. 
however i can not figure out how to use it the proper way. i keep getting an error on authProvider and i can;t find what this needs to do.

`private async void LoadUsers()
        {
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var user = await graphClient.Me
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
        }`

i have not yet made an authProvide instace because i cant find anything that works

Comment: You will first have to register your user or service calling the API via Graph.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api

Quote:
Microsoft Graph is a RESTful web API that enables you to access Microsoft Cloud service resources. After you register your app and get authentication tokens for a user or service, you can make requests to the Microsoft Graph API.